# Approach to iterating a list

Tags: python, list, iteration

I'm pretty new to Python and am working on an existing code base.

I see this pattern in the code a bit:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    item = my_list[i]
    # process item
```

Is there a good reason why this should not be simplified to:

```
for item in my_list:
    # process item
```

I do not need the index of the item within the `for` loop, other than to dereference the list item itself. So is there a problem with the latter that I am not seeing?

Comment: They're both the same, but I don't see why you would do this. `foo` will always be the last element. The latter is cleaner

Comment: @Haidro I think we can assume there is some more code in the loop body.

Comment: @Haidro, delnan is correct. I'll make it clearer in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are excellent reasons to simplify that to the second form; it is the preferred Pythonic method; but just use `foo` directly:

```
for foo in my_list:
    # process item
```

If an index is needed *as well*, use `enumerate()`:

```
for i, foo in enumerate(my_list):
    # process item
```

Creating a `for` loop over the `range()` of the `len()` of the list is usually a sign someone moved to Python from a language without a `for each` construct, like C, and they have not yet gotten used to how Python `for` loops really work.

Comment: And the only reason I can think of (short of not being aware that `for blah in ` is usable), is that the loop is required to modify the list, but obviously that falls to your `enumerate` example ;)

Comment: @JonClements: The index would then still be off by one, you'd have to use a `while` loop in that case.

Comment: @JonClements: Sorry, I was assuming that by modification you meant the usual "if I remove elements things don't work" loop problems.